# Where to Put App-wide Logic - Angular (2+)

Tags: angular

In AngularJS, I just stuck app wide logic in the run.js. For instance:

```
// runs when the app viewport/window gets focus, such as when switching tabs and back
$window.onfocus = function() {
    redirectIfUserChange(); // or any other arbitrary logic
};
```

The most similar thing in Angular seems to be the main.ts. However, I'm not sure on the reasons that is a good or bad idea. Perhaps one might suggest running all of this in the root (most parent) component upon init.

**Questions**

1) What is the best practice for this kind of stuff in Angular (2+)?

2) Are there any other good things to be aware of when attempting to incorporate app wide logic?

Comment: Before downvoting, please note that a lot of people search for something like this and it would be great to have a good resource here. If you still feel compelled to do so, please leave suggestions on how to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put app wide logic in `app.component.ts`. It will be first to be initialized and you can put logics needed app-wide here.

Anything which was put in `app.run` in angularJs can be put in `app.component.ts`

eg: **Things like listening to route events can be put here.**